# From Where Comes the Second Name in a Label in an Eagle Schema

Tags: eaglecad

I created a schema in Eagle and named some nets "BEAT_1", "BEAT_2", "BEAT_3", etc. But after adding labels to this nets, there is a second name in the label "BEAT_1/2.2A".

**From where comes the "2.2A" part of the name?**

**How can I get rid of this second name?**

[image: Labels in Schema]

Comment: Have you got more than one sheet? If so, it is indicating that they connect to the part named 2A on sheet 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have more than one sheet in your schematic.

Usually when you have more than one sheet, and the net extends over more than one sheet, then the labels will indicate one of the other sheets that the net extends on to, and in certain cases the part number that it connects to (if there is only one).

The format is:

`<net name>/<sheet number>.<part number>`

If it connects to more than one part on the other sheet, the part number will display as `??` to indicate that there is more than one part.

---

AFAIK, there is no way to turn this off, beyond using the Xref off version of the label (which simply displays text above the wire, rather than an arrow).

The two versions of the label look as follows:

[image: Lavel Styles]

Which version is used can be selected in the properties for the label, as shown below. Alternatively, you can run the `change xref off`/`change xref on` command and then click on the label.

[image: Properties Screen]